# Two different ways to send the ether

Tags: solidity, contract-development

What is the difference between these two?

```
 _instance.send(msg.value);

 address(_instance).send(msg.value);
```

both of them are giving me the same result on remix. Why?

So is this:

```
address(this).balance;

this.balance;
```

Am I missing something. Is there security consideration in using one of these?

Answer (score 2):

Those are not "two methods".
When you do `address(_instance)` or `address(this)` what you are doing is casting the _instance/this object into the type `address`.

Casting means taking an object of a certain data type and converting it into another data type.

For example, if you had a `uint8 number` and you wanted to do a power operation with it, given that uint8 would not have the capacity to hold a very large number, you would first cast it into a bigger int like this: `uint256(number)`

In your example above, you are taking a contract object and casting it into an address, which basically gives you the address of the contract.

Comment: So both of them are the same and there is nothing to be bothered about?